# Javadoc not generating comments for inherited methods

Tags: java, ant, javadoc

I am using Ant to create my documentation. I used `{@inheritDoc}` for methods such as `equals`, `hashCode`, and `toString`. However, no description shows up for these methods. See screenshot:

[image]

Here is my Ant script:

```
<project name="javadoc" default="javadoc.tool">
  <description>
    Provides JavaDoc. 
  </description>

  <import file="build.xml" />
  <property name="javadoc.dir" location="${build.dir}/javadoc" />
  <property name="javadoc.failonerror" value="false" />

  <target name="javadoc.tool" depends="compile" description="Generate JavaDoc.">
    <mkdir dir="${javadoc.dir}" />
    <javadoc classpathref="compile.classpath"
             sourcepath="${src.dir}"
             destdir="${javadoc.dir}"
             author="true"
             version="true"
             use="true"
             package="true"
             overview="${src.dir}/overview.html"
             windowtitle="${system.name} API"
             doctitle="${system.name} API"
             failonerror="${javadoc.failonerror}"
             excludepackagenames="junit"
             linksource="true" />
  </target>
</project>
```

How can I get descriptions for inherited methods to show up in the documentation? Your advice will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to inherit the docs from the standard Java classes then you need to include JDK `src.zip` in the sourcepath, I think. *(You may need to unzip it as well; I don't recall.)*

That said, if your methods to something "unexpected", you should write your own docs anyway. If they don't, IMO you don't really *need* the description for them.

Comment: Using Oracle JDK 1.7, specifying `src.zip` as a `sourcepath`
failed due to errors. Unzipping `src.zip` worked, albeit with 2705 warnings.

Comment: @cpeisert There would likely be warnings regarding internal classes; haven't tried it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but the proper way to link to external APIs with the javadoc Ant task is to use nested `<link>` elements. For instance, to link to Java 7 APIs:

```
<javadoc ... >
  ...
  <link href="http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/" />
</javadoc>
```

Please read the [related Ant documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javadoc.html) for all the details.